# Demand-side effects meaning

Tags: supply-and-demand, applied-econometrics, regression, keynesian-economics, demand

I found the term of *demand-side effects* in the abstract of the following paper: 
journals-sagepub-com/ DOI/abs/10.1177/0974930619872083 .

What does that mean? Can you explain it to me please? I need it for a project and I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demand side effects:     Effects to the economy whenever the demand-side factors (the components of GDP [in the abstracts case, Government spending]) either increases or decreases.

Demand AD (GDP) = C + I  + G +X-M

https://www.economicshelp.org/blog/2671/economics/factors-affecting-economic-growth/

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: you're welcome friend.  Good luck on your project.

Comment: In the end the Professor said she liked it a lot. Lots of thanks  again!

Comment: thats great to hear friend!  I am glad I was able to support your efforts.